# LibGDX: How to add Google Mobile Vision API to a LibGDX project?

Tags: gradle, libgdx, build.gradle, google-vision

Maybe the answer is simple, however I could not find anything that could help me yet.
Basicaly, I want to add the Google Vision API to my project. I tried this by putting

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.0.0+'
```

in `build.gradle` `dependencies` in the Android module, like in this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#3). This did not work (maybe I should write it somewhere else? I can't figure it out). Now there are many inspections shown in this `build.gradle`. There is said that there components cannot be applied to `groovy.lang.Closure`.

I have installed the Google Repository. And I've completed that tutorial, which is not LibGDX, and everything works fine there.

So how to make it work with LibGDX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add:

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-vision:v1-rev20-1.22.0'
```

into root `build.gradle` (located in the root of your project) under android dependencies and not to module specific one.

```
project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        ........
        compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-vision:v1-rev20-1.22.0'
    }
}
```